# Fixed header not working properly with one version of jquery code, why is my second version so slow in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, fade

Here's a link first of all to a test page: http://www.mindevo.com/tests/tacos.html

Edit: I set up a jsfiddle to play with it as well: http://jsfiddle.net/E4Uav/1/

So I set up my page with a fixed background on the main feature div. Here's the basic framework of how the page is set up:

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="game2 dark"></div>
<div class="game3 dark"></div>
<div class="gave4 dark"></div>
```

Here's the corresponding css for that setup:

```
.main{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15em;
  background: white url('../images/tacobg.png') no-repeat fixed 0 0;
  padding-top:1em;
}
.game2, .game3, .game4 {
  height:13.3333em;
  width:100%;}
.game2 {background:rgb(0,51,16) url('../images/potatobackground.png') no-repeat 0 0em;}
.game3 {background-color: rgb(0, 1, 82);}
.game4 {background-color: rgb(255, 80, 0);}
.dark {opacity: .5;}
```

Now that all works just fine by itself. Then I added a bit of javascript to tell the next div to fade in once it reaches a certain point, and when I add the javascript then something gets broken.

This happens only in Chrome (also checked Chrome Canary) but not in Firefox. When you scroll down the fade in happens perfectly. Now when you scroll up for some reason the background becomes no longer fixed for a moment, you scroll all the way up and some whitespace appears above the image (which is the background color for the "main" div, not the entire page).

Here's the javascript I'm using to fade in the "game2" div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){

         $('.dark').addClass('show');

      } else {

         $('.dark').removeClass('show');

        };    
   });
});
```

EDIT: So just to get around that bug I learned a different way to achieve what I was trying to do....

Here's my new javascript, it skips adding / removing the classes (the transitions are really odd, and when it triggers is really slow in Chrome, but it seems to work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.dark').each(function(i){

   var half_object = $(this).position().top + ($(this).outerHeight()/2);
   var bottom_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
   var bottom_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();

   if(bottom_window > half_object){
    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},200);
   }
   else if(bottom_object > $(window).scrollTop()) {
    $(this).animate({'opacity':'.5'},200);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

It could use some speeding up, it takes forever to happen in Firefox now, the second and third s which use the "dark" class don't get their opacity changed for quite some time. To the point where it would make user interaction annoying.

What is the cause of this delay? How can I speed this code up so it just triggers when the div is halfway displayed, and then when it's above the top or below the bottom of the viewport it fades back to 50% opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong.  It looks like a bug in Chrome?  For me it fixes itself after a delay in Chrome, and doesn't occur in IE.